# How to use the ImageReader that appeared in Android 4.4?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-4.4-kitkat

Android 4.4 Kit Kat introduced the [ImageReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html) class for accessing the image in the Surface, useful for real-time processing of a camera preview. However, I can't figure out how to link it to the Surface or use it. Anybody have any insights or short example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an example in the camera [CTS tests](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/kitkat-release/tests/tests/hardware/src/android/hardware/camera2/cts/ImageReaderTest.java).

As noted in the comments, ImageReader isn't actually usable until 5.0 ("Lollipop").

Comment: Actually, those CTS tests use the new camera2 API that aren't public APIs yet (although they seem to become public in L according to the developer preview). So from the use cases listed in the 4.4 documentation of ImageReader, MediaCodec and MediaPlayer aren't compatible (yet?), and the camera can't use it (yet) - does it work with Renderscript in 4.4?

Comment: The camera2 APIs are public now.