# CPU processing on camera image

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

Currently I'm showing a preview of the camera on the screen providing the camera preview texture - `camera.setPreviewTexture(...)` (doing it using opengl of course).

I have a native library which get `bytes[]` as an image, and return a `byte[]` - the result image related to the input image. I want to call it, and then draw the input image and the result to the screen - one on each other.

I know that in Opengl, in order to get the data of texture back in the CPU we must be read it using `glReadPixel` and after process i will have to load the result to a texture - which will have big impact on performances to do it each frame.

I thought about using `camera.setPreviewCallback(...)`, There i'm getting the frame (Calling the process method and transfer the result to the my SurfaceView), and parallel continue using the texture preview Technic for drawing on the screen, but than i'm afraid of synchronizing between the frames that i got in the `previewCallback` to those i got in the texture.

Am i missing anything ? or there is not easy way to solve this issue?

Comment: You are right, there is no synchronization between SurfaceTexture and onPreviewFrame. Only few minutes ago, I posted a similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35341780/192373). Please check how relevant it is for you.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to read, but sadly, This is what I've thought

Comment: Don't punish the messenger ;) Pushing the camera frames to custom texture is quite efficient on Android; we have achieved 30 FPS at 720p.

Comment: I didn't quite get you here. _Pushing the camera frames to custom texture_ ? I need the data of the frame as byte array - this is my problem. I'm doing some manipulation with the frag-shader but the main algorithm is in the native which get this array of data

Comment: As **fadden** [explains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35345708/192373) in more detail, you need to pass the pixels to display; one of the most efficient mechanisms on Android today is with `glTexImage2D()` (or `glTexSubImage2D()`)

Answer (score 1):

One approach that may be useful is to direct the output of the Camera to an [ImageReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html), which provides a Surface.  Each frame sent to the Surface is made available as YUV data without a copy, which makes it faster than some of the alternatives.  The variations in color formats (stride, alignment, interleave) are handled by ImageReader.

Since you want the camera image to be presented simultaneously with the processing output, you can't send frames down two independent paths.

When the frame is ready, you will need to do a color-space conversion and upload the pixels with `glTexImage2D()`.  This will likely be the performance-limiting factor.

From the comments it sounds like you're familiar with image filtering using a fragment shader; for anyone else who finds this, you can see an example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg).

Comment: You are referencing to use `camera2` api.. but unfortunately my min sdk is 18.. So i guess i have to do it with the `camera.setpreviewcallbackwithbuffer(...)`

Comment: Actually, the original camera API can send the output to a Surface, but ImageReader wasn't introduced until API 19.

Comment: And is it possible to connect the surface from the ImagerReader to the camera (camera1 api) ?

Comment: Yes. The ImageReader class was actually added by the Camera team. Camera2 wasn't available until API 21.

Comment: How can we attach it to the camera preview? It is getting 'SurfaceTexture' or 'SurfaceHolder'. And image reader provide simple surface. Can you refer to example?

Comment: Damn it, I did it again... I keep forgetting that the class was initially useless. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147519/how-to-use-the-imagereader-that-appeared-in-android-4-4 , particularly mstorsjo's comment.) You are correct, Camera2 API is required.